# Studying a differential equation in high frequency regime.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say I have a DE,

$$
\dddot y = 4 \omega^2(1 + \epsilon \cos(wt)) \dot y - 2 \epsilon \omega^2 \Omega \sin (\Omega t), \tag 1
$$

where $\epsilon \ll 1$ and $\Omega \gg \omega$.

> I basically want to study this type of DE. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Perturbation analysis would be a better bet, imo.